# Pandas: TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am facing TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

```
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
    user = data_sims.index[i]
    serial = data_sims.columns[j]

    if dataUser.ix[i][j] == 1:
        data_sims.ix[i][j] = 0
    else:
        serial_top_names = data_neighbours.ix[serial][1:10]
        serial_top_sims = dataSim.ix[serial].sort_values(ascending=False)[1:10]
        user_preferences = dataUser.ix[user,serial_top_names]

        data_sims.ix[i][j] = getScore(user_preferences,serial_top_sims)
```

Detailed Error:

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      9         else:
     10             serial_top_names = data_neighbours.ix[serial][1:10]
---> 11             serial_top_sims = dataSim.ix[serial].sort_values(ascending=False)[1:10]
     12             user_preferences = dataUser.ix[user,serial_top_names]
     13 

TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'
```

I tried using following but didn't work

```
pd.DataFrame.sort_values(dataSim,ascending=[0])[1:10]
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Based on the error message, you might need to put `by=someSortingFunction` as an argument, but I am unsure

Comment: When you define `serial = data_sims.columns[j]`, you use columns but with `dataSim.ix[serial]` you are indexing on rows. Is that intentional? It should still return a Series and shouldn't require a `by`  parameter but that might be related to the issue. Also what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @ayhan yes its intentional. 0.19.2 is version of pandas I'm using. http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/collaborative-filtering-with-python/ is the reference

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example it makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation for Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) mentions:

```
DataFrame.sort_values(by,
                      axis=0,
                      ascending=True,
                      inplace=False,
                      kind='quicksort',
                      na_position='last')
```

**by** : str or list of str
Name or list of names which refer to the axis items.

In my example:

```
df.groupby('product').agg({'weight':'sum'}).sort_values(by='weight')
```

Adding by='weight' solved the TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'

Answer (score 1):

The dataframe may have multiple columns, so specify the column you want to sort by.

```
df = df.sort_values(by='sentence_length').reset_index(drop=True)
```